# Cost of simple non object oriented Neural Network "jumping"

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am building a sketch of a neural network in Python 3.4 with numpy and matrices to learn a simple XOR.
My Notation is as follows:

*a* is the activity of a neuron

*z* is the input of a neuron

*W* is a weight matrix with size R^{#number of neurons in previous layer}x{#number of neurons in next layer}

*B* is a vector of bias values

After implementing a very simple network in python, everything works fine when training on only a single input vector. However, when training on all four training examples of XOR the error function shows a quite weird behaviour (see picture) and the output of the network is always roughly 0.5.
Changing the network size, the learning rate or the training epochs does not seem to help.

[image: Cost J while only training on one training example]
Cost J while only training on one training example

[image: Cost J while training with all training examples]
Cost J while training with all training examples

This is the code for the network:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


Js = []
start = time.time()
np.random.seed(2)


#Sigmoid        
def activation(x, derivative = False):
    if(derivative):
        a = activation(x)
        return a * (1 - a)
    else:
        return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

def cost(output, target):
    return (1/2) * np.sum((target - output)**2)


INPUTS = np.array([
    [0, 1],
    [1, 0],
    [0, 0],
    [1, 1],
])
TARGET = np.array([
    [1],
    [1],
    [0],
    [0],
])

"Hyper-Parameters"
# Layer Structure
LAYER = [2, 3, 1]
LEARNING_RATE = 0.1
ITERATIONS = int(1e3)

# Init Weights
W1 = np.random.rand(LAYER[0], LAYER[1])
W2 = np.random.rand(LAYER[1], LAYER[2])

# Init Biases
B1 = np.random.rand(LAYER[1], 1)
B2 = np.random.rand(LAYER[2], 1)

for i in range(0, ITERATIONS):
    exampleIndex = i % len(INPUTS)
    #exampleIndex = 2
    "Forward Pass"
    # Layer One Activity (Input layer)
    A0 = np.transpose(INPUTS[exampleIndex:exampleIndex+1])

    # Layer Two Activity (Hidden Layer)
    Z1 = np.dot(np.transpose(W1), A0) + B1
    A1 = activation(Z1)

    # Layer Three Activity (Output Layer)
    Z2 = np.dot(np.transpose(W2), A1) + B2
    A2 = activation(Z2)

    # Output
    O = A2

    # Cost J

    # Target Vector T
    T = np.transpose(TARGET[exampleIndex:exampleIndex+1])
    J = cost(O, T)
    Js.append(J)

    print("J = {}".format(J))
    print("I = {}, O = {}".format(A0, O))

    "Backward Pass"

    # Calculate Delta of output layer
    D2 = (O - T) * activation(Z2, True)

    # Calculate Delta of hidden layer
    D1 = np.dot(W2, D2) * activation(Z1, True)

    # Calculate Derivatives w.r.t. W2
    DerW2 = np.dot(A1, np.transpose(D2))
    # Calculate Derivatives w.r.t. W1
    DerW1 = np.dot(A0, np.transpose(D1))

    # Calculate Derivatives w.r.t. B2
    DerB2 = D2
    # Calculate Derivatives w.r.t. B1
    DerB1 = D1

    "Update Weights and Biases"

    W1 -= LEARNING_RATE * DerW1
    B1 -= LEARNING_RATE * DerB1

    W2 -= LEARNING_RATE * DerW2
    B2 -= LEARNING_RATE * DerB2

# Show prediction

print("Time elapsed {}s".format(time.time() - start))    
plt.plot(Js)
plt.ylabel("Cost J")
plt.xlabel("Iterations")
plt.show()
```

What could be the reason for this strange behaviour in my implementation?

Answer (score 2):

I think your cost function is jumping since you perform your weight updates after each sample. However, your network is training the correct behavior nonetheless:

```
479997
J = 4.7222501603409765e-05
I = [[1]
 [0]], O = [[ 0.99028172]]
T = [[1]]
479998
J = 7.3205311398742e-05
I = [[0]
 [0]], O = [[ 0.01210003]]
T = [[0]]
479999
J = 4.577485181547362e-05
I = [[1]
 [1]], O = [[ 0.00956816]]
T = [[0]]
480000
J = 4.726257702199439e-05
I = [[0]
 [1]], O = [[ 0.9902776]]
T = [[1]]
```

The cost function shows some interesting behavior: the training process reaches a point where jumps in the cost function will become quite small. 
You can reproduce this with the code below (I have only made slight changes; note that I trained over much more epochs):

```
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


Js = []
start = time.time()
np.random.seed(2)


#Sigmoid        
def activation(x, derivative = False):
    if(derivative):
        a = activation(x)
        return a * (1 - a)
    else:
        return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

def cost(output, target):
    return (1/2) * np.sum((target - output)**2)


INPUTS = np.array([[0, 1],[1, 0],[0, 0],[1, 1]])
TARGET = np.array([[1],[1],[0],[0]])

"Hyper-Parameters"
# Layer Structure
LAYER = [2, 3, 1]
LEARNING_RATE = 0.1
ITERATIONS = int(5e5)

# Init Weights
W1 = np.random.rand(LAYER[0], LAYER[1])
W2 = np.random.rand(LAYER[1], LAYER[2])

# Init Biases
B1 = np.random.rand(LAYER[1], 1)
B2 = np.random.rand(LAYER[2], 1)

for i in range(0, ITERATIONS):
    exampleIndex = i % len(INPUTS)
    # exampleIndex = 2
    "Forward Pass"
    # Layer One Activity (Input layer)
    A0 = np.transpose(INPUTS[exampleIndex:exampleIndex+1])

    # Layer Two Activity (Hidden Layer)
    Z1 = np.dot(np.transpose(W1), A0) + B1
    A1 = activation(Z1)

    # Layer Three Activity (Output Layer)
    Z2 = np.dot(np.transpose(W2), A1) + B2
    A2 = activation(Z2)

    # Output
    O = A2

    # Cost J

    # Target Vector T
    T = np.transpose(TARGET[exampleIndex:exampleIndex+1])
    J = cost(O, T)
    Js.append(J)

    # print("J = {}".format(J))
    # print("I = {}, O = {}".format(A0, O))
    # print("T = {}".format(T))
    if ((i+3) % 20000 == 0):
        print(i)
        print("J = {}".format(J))
        print("I = {}, O = {}".format(A0, O))
        print("T = {}".format(T))
    if ((i+2) % 20000 == 0):
        print(i)
        print("J = {}".format(J))
        print("I = {}, O = {}".format(A0, O))
        print("T = {}".format(T))
    if ((i+1) % 20000 == 0):
        print(i)
        print("J = {}".format(J))
        print("I = {}, O = {}".format(A0, O))
        print("T = {}".format(T))
    if (i % 20000 == 0):
        print(i)
        print("J = {}".format(J))
        print("I = {}, O = {}".format(A0, O))
        print("T = {}".format(T))

    "Backward Pass"

    # Calculate Delta of output layer
    D2 = (O - T) * activation(Z2, True)

    # Calculate Delta of hidden layer
    D1 = np.dot(W2, D2) * activation(Z1, True)

    # Calculate Derivatives w.r.t. W2
    DerW2 = np.dot(A1, np.transpose(D2))
    # Calculate Derivatives w.r.t. W1
    DerW1 = np.dot(A0, np.transpose(D1))

    # Calculate Derivatives w.r.t. B2
    DerB2 = D2
    # Calculate Derivatives w.r.t. B1
    DerB1 = D1

    "Update Weights and Biases"

    W1 -= LEARNING_RATE * DerW1
    B1 -= LEARNING_RATE * DerB1

    W2 -= LEARNING_RATE * DerW2
    B2 -= LEARNING_RATE * DerB2

# Show prediction

print("Time elapsed {}s".format(time.time() - start))    
plt.plot(Js)
plt.ylabel("Cost J")
plt.xlabel("Iterations")
plt.savefig('cost.pdf')
plt.show()
```

In order to reduce fluctuations in the cost function, one usually uses multiple data samples before performing an update (some averaged update), but I see that this is difficult in a set containing only four different training events. 
So, to conclude this rather long answer: your cost function jumps because it is calculated for every single example and not for an average of multiple examples. However, the network output follows the distribution of the XOR function quite well, so you don't need to change it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you explain what you mean with averaged update in a bit more detail, please? Do you mean calculating the derivatives for every training example and only updating the weights with an average of derivatives after like four feed forward passes?

Comment: You might want to have a look at this: http://sebastianruder.com/optimizing-gradient-descent/. It is explained quite well there. Basically, you have trained with what is called the stochastic gradient descent in the article. The other extremum is the batch gradient descent (to stick with the nomenclature used in the article). If the data set contains more different data, the mini-batch gradient descent usually yields a good trade-off of fast convergence and small fluctuations (the jumps in the cost function).